# Images are not displaying in Laravel 4.1 Framework

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display images of products from database but it shows blank space

```
{{ HTML::image($product->image, $product->title, array('class'=>'feature', 'width'=>'240', 'height'=>'127')) }}
```

Comment: what is the generated HTML code?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo the generated htm code is   <img src="http://localhost:8000/" class="feature" width="240" height="120">

Comment: As you can see generated code is invalid, make sure your $product->image has correct value, apparently it is not correct

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo which value need to be add for display images

Comment: How should I know? First  parameter to html::image should be path to the image and $product->image is empty - you need to determine why